# How is Devise's secret_key used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I've been using Devise for a while now and have wondered how the secret key is used. I looked through the source for references to `secret_key`, but it wasn't clear to me exactly what we do with it. It seems to me that it might be related to session security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `secret_key` in devise is used to hash passwords and generate hashed tokens (used for password-resets, email-confirm tokens etc)